# Dialogflow and firebase not connecting

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

Hi I have created a dialogflow agent that is supposed to capture info from users and store it within a real time firebase database. Here is the in line editor code

```js
        const functions = require('firebase-functions');
        const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
        const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

        // initialise DB connection
        const admin = require('firebase-admin');
        admin.initializeApp({
          credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
          databaseURL: 'ws:database URL',
        });



        process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

        exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
          const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
          console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
          console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

          function welcome(agent) {
            agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
          }

    function handleAge(agent) {
       const age = agent.parameters.person;
         return admin.database().ref('ageInfo').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
         var averageAge = snapshot.child("runningAverage").val();
          agent.add(`Our recorded average age is ` + averageAge);
        });


      }

      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
      intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
      intentMap.set('1_1_name', handleAge);
      // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
      // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

I have the database setup and read and write priviliges enabled. However the webhook still fails with the only error being time elapsed. I have an idea that the admin credentials part may be wrong but I am not sure how to correct it. please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising the connection to the DB with the wrong credentials. Try it like this:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

It seems `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` is not working for you. Instead of setting them by default be leaving empty `admin.initializeApp();` or using `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` you could check the [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase#initialize-app) function documentation to know what parameters you can pass.

This is the ***package.json*** I used:

```js
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.13.0 "
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.3"
  }
}
```

### Docs

You could also watch these other docs for getting more info about the Node.JS firebase-SDK

- [firebase. database. Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Database.html)
- [Firebase JavaScript SDK Reference For Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase)